# Colocar em ordem alfabética+numérica lista dinâmica

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá,
estou tentando ordenar uma lista pelo data-char. Preciso que o fique em ordem decrescente. Não entendo muito de javascript/jquery, mas pelas minhas pesquisas, cheguei ao código abaixo. Porém ele tá me retornando a ordem:c8 c2 b1 b13 a20 a18 a8 a2 a7, precisava que fosse tudo em ordem decrescente: c8 c2 b13 b1 a20 a18 a8 a7 a2. O que estou fazendo errado? [Aqui está o Jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/camilam/3hqfztkd/) Obrigada.

```js
$(".pecas li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.pecas');

function sort_li(a, b) {
  var va = $(a).data('char').toString().charCodeAt(0);
  var vb = $(b).data('char').toString().charCodeAt(0);
  if (va < 'a'.charCodeAt(0)) va += 100;
  if (vb < 'a'.charCodeAt(0)) vb += 100;
  return vb > va ? 1 : -1;
}
```

```css
li{list-style:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="pecas">
  <li class="foto" data-char="a20">a20</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="a18">a18</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="c8">c8</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="a8">a8</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="a2">a2</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="a7">a7</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="b1">b1</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="c2">c2</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="b13">b13</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma é separar as letras da parte numérica. Se a letra for igual, irá eliminar o que for letra e comparar a parte numérica e retornar o que for maior primeiro. Caso contrário, retorna o valor maior da letra pelo `.charCodeAt`.

```js
$(".pecas li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.pecas');

function sort_li(a, b) {
   
   var r = /[a-z]/; // expressão regular para eliminar as letras
   var aD = $(a).data('char'); // valor de data-char em "a"
   var bD = $(b).data('char'); // valor de data-char em "b"
   var va = aD.charCodeAt(0); // valor da letra em "a"
   var vb = bD.charCodeAt(0); // valor da letra em "b"

   if(va == vb){ // se as letras forem iguais
      var aN = parseInt(aD.replace(r, '')); // valor numérico em "a"
      var bN = parseInt(bD.replace(r, '')); // valor numérico em "b"
      return bN > aN ? 1 : -1;
   }

   return vb > va ? 1 : -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="pecas">
  <li class="foto" data-char="a20">a20</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="a18">a18</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="c8">c8</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="a8">a8</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="a2">a2</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="a7">a7</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="d1">d1</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="d11">d11</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="z8">z8</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="b1">b1</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="c2">c2</li>
  <li class="foto" data-char="b13">b13</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Obrigada sam! Funcionou perfeitamente!